# Where can I find how much one XRP (Ripple unit) is worth?

Tags: ripple

XRP are the units of the new Ripple.com system.

Where can I find how much they're worth right now? Historic charts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 2**: There are now more traditional price / volume charts:

- [BTC:Bitstamp/XRP at RippleCharts.com](https://ripplecharts.com/market/BTC%3aBitstamp/XRP)
- [USD:Bitstamp/XRP at RippleCharts.com](https://ripplecharts.com/market/USD%3aBitstamp/XRP)

**Update**: [Ripple Live Orderbook and Charts](http://xrp.webr3.org/) by webr3 provides various bitstamp style charts and orderbooks for various XRP/xxx pairs.

**Update**: The [Ripple Ledger Explorer](http://rippledb.com/) by melvster shows a graph of Ripple vs Bitcoin prices.  It also shows recent ledger activity.

---

Early on there was also a manually-updated list at:

- [Ripple: XRP Price Tracker](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=148185.0)

The discussion there had a nice example of what an order book snapshot from the ripple client looks like, with headers.

The #ripple-market irc channel at freenode.net also shows real-time trades via a "Streaming exchange feed for notable #ripple gateways" all trades.  You can see it via

- [freenode Web IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net/)

A trade example looks like this:

```
< ripplebot> TRD bitstamp 730.698114 @ 48,713.2076 BTC rwdLV79WzXmFuzP2cBwTG6mtXcfSnCjtoF #142
```

I assume that means that the price for that transaction was 48,713 XRD per BTC, and I'm guessing that 730 XRD were traded at that price via bitstamp, but I haven't seen good documentation yet.

Here is an example ASK report:

```
ASK bitstamp 347.152555 @ 41,854.251463 BTC rwdLV79WzXmFuzP2cBwTG6mtXcfSnCjtoF #143
```

The code for ripplebot can be found at

- [rippleFoundation/ripple-watch · GitHub](https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple-watch)

Comment: That thread is terrible, people arguing about stuff.

Comment: @Lohoris Yes indeed.  But it is so far the only place I've found where you can get an instant view of the trend.  So just pay attention to the first post, and hope it is updated, and correct.  If you really care, watch the IRC channel, or get a funded account from which you can observe the order book.

Comment: This new ripplecharts.com is good!

Answer (score 5):

I just made a simple website which shows XRP price for different gateways. No historic charts yet.. http://xrpvalue.com/

Comment: This is my new favorite "what's the price of an XRP" site.

Comment: Thanks :). I'm open to suggestions and pull requests on github. https://github.com/vhpoet/xrpvalue.com

Answer (score 2):

Since the internal trade history will be public, I guess a service could be built to show price statistics. You would watch the prices of the most traded IOUs, presumably from gateways. Examples: wexUSD, wexBTC, wexEUR, etc.

The site could have several tools to group several currencies of the same denomination (but different issuers) averaging by volume or something like that. It could be similar to bitcoincharts, but pulling the data from the ledger instead of the exchange's servers.

I guess the [core](https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple) needs to be released first.

Answer (score 2):

You can check Ripple (XRP) market chart at [Bitcoincharts.com/market/Ripple](http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/rippleXRP.html)

Answer (score 1):

The orderbook ([found inside the Ripple client](https://ripple.com/client/#trade) once you're logged in and funded) does in fact show the price, it's just a huge spread and confusing UI that makes it difficult to understand now.

Right now, the best bid is:

10BTC   10BTC   5,000.00000XR

And the best ask is:

43,998.00000XRP 10BTC   10B

Which means someone is proposing to buy BTC at the price of 5000 XRPs, and another person is offering to sell BTC at the price of 43,399.8 XRP. So, the spread is huge, but one can still say the "price" of 1 XRP right now is somewhere between 0.000002 and 0.0002 BTC

Comment: Seems like a typo there - do you mean 43,998 XRP rather than 43,399.8?  And do you need to divide by the units there (10 BTC) or is that actually the total price?

Comment: @nealmcb - could be. Anyway the answer isn't the price at any point in time, it's just a place where the price can be found out.

Comment: Unfortunately, the price spread you link to can only be found out after opening an account and getting "funded" with 300 ripples.  So while I appreciate the concrete helpful nature of this post, it would help even more if it was internally consistent and indicated what the columns mean.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm replying to a post of 2013. I'm looking for historical Ripple pricing in USD from it's launch in February 2nd, 2013 till the end of 2013. Does anyone know where I can find this?

Answer (score -2):

It will be worth different things to different people in different instances. There won't be any global price just like there isn't any global price for bitcoin. Multiple exchange rates exist on multiple exchanges. MtGox is just the biggest and thus often quoted. Some people are paying more some people are paying less than the MtGox rate. This creates opportunities for arbitrage.
This only accounts for other currencies and not for example how many gallons of gas a bitcoin is worth.

Comment: Mmmh no, actually there is a global BTC exchange rate: arbitrage makes them all converge to the same. If some rate is higher or lower there is always a reason, such as higher operation costs, no API access, etc.

Comment: Arbitrage will make them converge, but not perfectly, otherwise it by definition would no longer occur. As long as it still occurs there must be multiple exchange rates.

Answer (score -2):

You can find how much one XRP (ripple) is worth at...

http://www.RipplePrice.com and also at http://www.DigiPrices.com

The rate shown is the mid-market rate at Bitstamp.

Disclosure: I created these sites. I'd appreciate any feedback.